# wordpress backend redirect to blank page after changing to https

Tags: wordpress, https

thanks in advance for your help! :)

my webpage is running on cloudflare and I activated the flexible ssl certificate. I ran into some redirect errors and also could not log into the admin panel. so I installed a plugin called "cloudflare flexible ssl" which prevents the redirect loop happening.

However, every time I am saving something in Wordpress (posting smth, activating plugins, installing plugins, actually every action you can perform) it redirects to a blank page. When I go back, everything got saved/the action was executed. I tried to turn on the debug log but it did not work.

Anyone got an idea how to proceed? Do you need any more information?

for example: when trying to activate the preview function it shows that it wants to get to that page

[[image: for example: when trying to activate the preview function it shows that it wants to get to that page]

But it opens this one
[image: But it opens this one]

thanks again!

Comment: what I realized is, at least I think this might be the problem, that when I click the "save" button it tries to go to http:// and gets redirected to https:// but doing that maybe forgets what it wanted to do? :D sounds kinda funny tho but I realized it first tries to access the http:// domain.

Comment: Error Plugin Installation:

Installation failed: {"success":true,"data":{"install":"plugin","slug":"codeflavors-vimeo-video-post-lite","pluginName":"WordPress Vimeo videos","debug":["Downloading the installer package from https:\/\/downloads.wordpress.org\/plugin\/codeflavors-vimeo-video-post-lite.zip&#160;&hellip;","Extracting the package&#160;&hellip;","The plugin will be installed&#160;&hellip;","The plugin was installed."],"activateUrl":"https:\/\/wu-marketingclub.at\/wp-admin\/plugins.php?_wpnonce=ad0ba9f820&action=activate&plugin=codeflavors-vimeo-video-post-lite\/main.php"}}

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your Hosting to a https URl, you have to change all URLs in your Wordpress Installation to https. 
(Wordpress Adress and Site Adress)

Comment: I did that. At least I am using "force https" and also cloud flare should automatically rewrite all of them. Last but not least I ran a script which replaced all http by https and to make sure I also wrote a rewrite into my htaccess? Maybe too much? :D